# AWS: Is there a way to copy csv file from S3 on to a Redshift database without providing credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if there was any way to give permissions to a Redshift database on some buckets so that it can copy csv files from that bucket without providing credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There's no way of verifying the requestor without credentials.